# Building a webpage that uses Node.js to scrape RSS in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, browserify

I have some coding experience but am pretty much brand new to Javascript and web development.

I'm trying to build a webpage whose primary functionality involves scraping an RSS feed from the National Weather Service (e.g. https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.0536&lon=-118.2455&FcstType=digitalDWML) and then parsing the output to display various parameters (temperature, humidity, etc.) as text.

I've looked into it and it seems like Node.js has a few different ways to scrape external webpages and return the source as an object. However, from what I understand, Node.js is designed for server-side applications, whereas I want to use it on an actual website that people can access. I'm stuck on the following:

1. How do I integrate Node.js functionality into the code of a webpage? Do Node.js scripts and other dependencies packaged through something like Browserify automatically "work" in a browser, or is there more to it?
2. Is there a self-contained Javascript editor that would allow me to utilize Node.js and other dependencies and debug scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is a means to execute JS programs on the command line. `<script>` elements are a means to execute JS programs in a webpage in a web browser.

Browiserify is a tool which takes a set of JS modules that use the *CommonJS module system* and turns them into a single file which doesn't depend on support for CommonJS. (Node.js uses the CommonJS module system, browsers do not).

It is possible to write JS code which runs both under Node.js and, using browserify, in a browser. Not all code which runs under Node.js can be converted to run in a browser. The code might depend on APIs which are built into Node.js but not browsers (such as file system access, or network socket support).

If you have code which depends on those APIs you'll need to either rewrite it so it uses features available in browsers instead, or run it server side and then provide a web service URL for the browser to access with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: So if I were to have a separate server-side script that only ran the scrape function, and then the client-side HTML called that script, that would work without using Browserify? Does anything need to be installed server-side in order for Node.js to run in that context?

Comment: Since the CommonJS code wouldn't run in the browser and you'd only use built-in browser APIs to make the HTTP request to it: Yes. You'd need to install Node.js on the server to run the program that depends on Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

## What your browser has

Your browser will show an HTML document, that will be a hierarchical structure and which will be styles by CSS and its behavior can be programmed via Javascript

## What your server sends

Since your browser receives the HTML, it is the job of your server to construct the HTML.

## Where should you scrape

You should scrape on your server unless you have a very good reason to do it on your client-side.

## What server should you choose

Basically NodeJS is a "good" choice. But other servers are good choices as well. You can easily generate HTML via virtually any server-side technologies, like Node JS, but you can do so via PHP, .NET, Java or other environments as well. However, since this is scraping, you will probably need a multithreading environment, so from this point of view Node JS is not the best choice, because it is event-loop-based.

## Bottom-line

You will need a multithreaded server technology to scrape and the ability to generate HTML to display your results in your browser. You may want to support polling or WebSockets for a real-time experience, but that's another topic.